# Can I get SQL Server Import Wizard to create PK's, FK's and Indexes?

Tags: sql-server, migration, import

I'm importing data from one SQLServer2005 instance to another using the Import wizard and getting the importer to drop/create the tables for me. This runs great but on the new server, the tables are created without PK's, FK's or indexes. Is there some option I can set in the importer to do this for me?

If not, is there some simple way to 'import' those definitions after the importer has run and created my tables and populated them?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is supported out of the box. As a workaround, ygiven a list of tables, you could use PowerShell, SMO, or TSQL to generate the scripts to create the missing objects

Comment: Thanks! I ended up generating creation-scripts and running them first, and then importing the data with the import wizard.

Comment: yeah sorry I wasn't thinking straight. The easiest way is to use the built script generation in Management studio. Glad to here you had success.